# Play Java, How to read a local JSON file and show as list on a body?

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am starting learning Play Java, and found many different samples (often without imports etc.) about how to do what explained on subject.
I am using Play 2.5 and JDK 8, and configured my own controller. The file is in a directory that I can access from the controller Java class, but not clear to me what is the best practice to read the JSON file: through Jackson? or java.io.* functions?
Is it possible to obtain a working minimal sample from an expert?
I tried following this guide, but the code goes always in error (sample code does't neither have the final comma!):
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJsonActions

Basically my json items.json is under ..workspace\play-java\app\data\items.json .

The JSON file is something like this:
[
  {
    "id": 10000000,
    "name": "name1",
    "starttime": "2015-06-18T06:26:56-07:00",
    "endtime": "2015-07-08T12:47:16-07:00"
  }, etc.
]

and I guess that in the function to read the file I need to specify the path 'app/data/items.json' or 'data/items.json'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to checkout those samples: http://www.lightbend.com/activator/templates

Comment: @Micky Can you give an example more concrete? Something like "I have a file in conf/myfile.json and want to load it to ****what you want to do****"

Comment: Sure @Salem, going to edit my question..

Comment: `workspace\play-java\app\data\items.json` isn't on the classpath, whereas anything in the `conf` folder is.  I suggest you move your `data` folder to `conf`, and use the injected `Environment` to obtain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to deliver JSON to the client, you can use the `Json` class to convert an input stream (or string) into a `JsonNode` and pass that directly back in the response.  Because you're using a `JsonNode`, the content type of the will be response will be set automatically.

(For this example, I created a file in `/conf` called `foo.json`.)

```
package controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import play.Environment;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class SomeController extends Controller {

    private final Environment env;

    @Inject
    public SomeController(final Environment env) {
        // the environment is used to access local files
        this.env = env;
    }

    public Result index() {
        try (InputStream is = env.resourceAsStream("/foo.json")) {
            final JsonNode json = Json.parse(is);
            return ok(json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return internalServerError("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Steve, thanks a lot for your help! But I am getting this error: Execution exception
[CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 0]]

Comment: Line 1, column 0 sounds like your JSON file is empty, or possibly can't be found.  I created a file in `conf/` called `foo.json` containing the following, and it worked fine: `{"foo":"bar"}`.

Comment: Yes, Steve. Definitely the best solution..tried and it worked. I didn't know about the conf as root point for the path, I moved there my data folder and it works very well. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved by myself with this basic code:

```
package controllers;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import play.Environment;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class CustomersController extends Controller {


    private final Environment env;

    @Inject
    public CustomersController(final Environment env) {
        // the environment is used to access local files
        this.env = env;
    }

    public Result index() {
        File file = new File("absolute path/items.json");

        try (
                FileInputStream is =new FileInputStream(file);
        ){
            final JsonNode json = Json.parse(is);
            return ok(json);
        } catch(IOException e){
            return internalServerError("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```